# YA/children series about a magical realm coexisting with ours and a talisman that only girls could hold

Tags: story-identification

I have memories of reading a book or series around 1996 in England.

It was, I think, set in England and involved some kids discovering a way to see the magical realm, which co-exists with the regular world. Being able to see it was conditional on something like holding a magical object.

A key macguffin of the series was "the talisman", a magical object that could only be safely touched by girls.  I think there were witches too, mostly as an airborne threat to be avoided on whatever journey they were on.

Comment: These elements remind me of Philip Pullman's [*His Dark Materials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials) trilogy (1995-2000). Did "daemons" (external manifestations of people's souls) feature in what you read?

Comment: It definitely wasn't HDM, I've read that too.

Comment: @Zoe umm... if a boy touched the talisman did it cause them to lose their memory or something. Was the main plot the girl having to retrieve the talisman from amongst a bunch of witches (while somehow invisible by a potion/cloak) that lived under a tree? Does the girl escape with help from a broom flying cat and they have to rush to get to the water first before the witches catch-up?

Comment: If so... Could be [The Wild Witches and the Talisman](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2167637.The_Wild_Witches_And_The_Talisman) which was part of the "Tim and the Hidden People" series...

Comment: I think it was! I vividly remember reading this series when I was a kid. I think I must have been younger than I thought I was reading these.

Comment: @Zoë I don't have the book - and can't find a synopsis online for it so I'd submit an answer but sadly it'd be lacking any resources to back it up so I'll refrain for now. Don't forget if you find out it's definitely that or something else you can always answer this question with the details yourself.